# How to insert div in table header and don't spoil table structure?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, resize

I'm trying to implement table with resizable columns. When I insert resizer `<div>` element in table header with `jQuery.after()` for each `<th>` entry the structure of the table is broken because browser interprets these new `<div>` elements as new column headers and changes column structure appropriately. Is it possible to insert several `<div>` elements into `<thead>` element and preserve old structure?

**Sample structure**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> col </th>
            <div style="width:2px;height:10px;">&nbsp</div>
            <th> col </th>
            <div style="width:2px;height:10px;">&nbsp</div>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td> col </td>
         <td> col </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you post a test case on fiddle

Comment: You can put a `<div>` only into cells. If you need one `div`, instead of a separate `div` in each cell, then maybe you could add a row, a cell with colspan, and then a div.

Comment: you're right I'll try to do it if this idea fails

Comment: @Arsen7 is right: a `div` can't be a direct child of a `tr`.

Comment: @chris5marsh: please post an answer with explanation

Comment: thanks for your answers I'll accept the one by Chris because of an interesting idea

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want to use `.append()` rather than `.after()`

```
$('th').append('<div class="resizer">');
```

Will add a div to each th.

Comment: well not really I don't want to insert a new element into header since it might change layout of header elements(and it does I know it because right now I'm inserting resizers inside headers not outside)

Comment: So where do you want to add the elements?